# Checking if non-member function that accepts T param exists

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I want to check if a non-member function that accepts a T parameter type exists. To do so I used `void_t` "trick" presented by Mr. Walter E. Brown at cppcon(same trick works without any problems to check if a member type or member function exists).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename...>
using void_t = void;

void Serialize(float&)
{
}

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_external_serialize : std::false_type
{
};

template<typename T>
struct has_external_serialize<T, void_t<decltype(Serialize(std::declval<T&>()))>> : std::true_type
{
};

void Serialize(int&)
{
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::cout<<has_external_serialize<float>::value<<has_external_serialize<int>::value;
}
```

This code prints `11` when compiled using GCC and `10` when compiled with clang(xcode 5.1.1).

My questions is - is this code correct? If yes, is there a bug in clang or a bug in GCC or the code is in some "implementation defined" area and I can't assume it will have same behaviour on all platforms?

Comment: Stick dependent types, and `std` types, before your specialization.  Other types use ADL.  Then clang will be happy.  I believe what you did is ill formed, but do not have time to prove it

Comment: Seems more like a bug in GCC (at least 4.9.0), because it prints `11` even for `struct has_external_serialize<T, void_t<decltype(SomeNonExistingFunc(std::declval<T&>()))>> : std::true_type`

Comment: @Felics: Welcome to CppCon! :-)

Comment: I can't answer your question, but here's a trick that g++ is also happy with: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7af49a7f53fbe4d

Comment: @Jamboree Thank you! I know there are other ways of solving this problem, some of them nice, like the one you posted, other with some horror code:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discrepancy between the compilers is caused by the definition of `void_t`:
[Is there a compiler bug exposed by my implementation of an is_complete type trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833356/is-there-a-compiler-bug-exposed-by-my-implementation-of-an-is-complete-type-trai/25833474#25833474) 
In short, the standard was unclear whether unused arguments in alias template specializations could result in substitution failure or are simply ignored. The resolution to [CWG issue 1558](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558) clarifies that the shorter definition of `void_t` in the question should work.

With that issue worked around using

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct make_void { typedef void type;};

template<typename... Ts>
using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;
```

[both compilers produce `10`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85471986c42f1629).

§14.6.4.2 [temp.dep.candidate]:

> For a function call that depends on a template parameter, the
>   candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1,
>   3.4.2, 3.4.3) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1) or qualified name lookup (3.4.3), only function declarations from the
>     template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations found in either the template definition context
>     or the template instantiation context are found.
>
> If the function name is an *unqualified-id* and the call would be
>   ill-formed or would find a better match had the lookup within the
>   associated namespaces considered all the function declarations with
>   external linkage introduced in those namespaces in all translation
>   units, not just considering those declarations found in the template
>   definition and template instantiation contexts, then the program has
>   undefined behavior.

Unqualified lookup for `Serialize` is performed in template definition context and will not find `Serialize(int &)`, and there's no ADL for an argument of type `int&`, so `10` is the correct output.