# Selecting traits with enable_if - works with clang, but not with gcc

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gcc, clang

I am working on a generic piece of (C++11) code that is supposed to work with `boost::multi_array`, `Eigen::Matrix`, and possibly other types of n-dimensional arrays. At several points I need access to the element-type of a given array-type. The boost arrays contain a typedef called `Element`, while the Eigen arrays contain a typedef called `Scalar`.

What I want is a type-trait that returns the element type of a given array type. Unfortunately, I cannot just template specialize the trait class for all possible array types, because Eigen uses expression-templates, and hence, there are infinitely many types of Eigen matrices. Therefore, I am using SFINAE with enable_if to implement my traits. The criterion which enable_if should select on is, whether a type has a typedef called `Element`, or one called `Scalar`.

For this to work I implemented type-traits `has_element`, and `has_scalar`, which determine whether the corresponding typedef exists. My implementation is inspired by [this blog post](http://pfultz2.com/blog/2014/08/17/type-requirements/) about type-requirements.

```
template <class T>
using ToVoid = void;

template <class T, class Enable = void>
struct has_scalar : public std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct has_scalar<T, ToVoid<typename T::Scalar>> : public std::true_type {};

template <class T, class Enable = void>
struct has_element : public std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct has_element<T, ToVoid<typename T::Element>> : public std::true_type {};
```

The idea is, that the compiler will pick the `false_type` version if the typedef is not presented, and will pick the *more specialized* `true_type` version if the typedef is present.

The actual trait to obtain the scalar type is implemented like this:

```
template <class Condition, class T = void>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<Condition::value, T>::type;

template <class T, class Enable = void>
struct scalar_of;

template <class T>
struct scalar_of<T, EnableIf<has_element<T>>> {
    using type = typename T::Element;
};

template <class T>
struct scalar_of<T, EnableIf<has_scalar<T>>> {
    using type = typename T::Scalar;
};

template <class T>
using ScalarOf = typename scalar_of<T>::type;
```

A simple example use case is this:

```
struct BoostArray {
    using Element = double;
};

struct EigenArray {
    using Scalar = float;
};


int main() {
    using std::is_same;
    assert((is_same<double, ScalarOf<BoostArray>>::value));
    assert((is_same<float, ScalarOf<EigenArray>>::value));
}
```

Now, the odd thing is that this works just fine with Clang 3.4. However, GCC 4.8.1 fails to compile this and gives the following error message:

```
test.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class T> using ScalarOf = typename scalar_of<T>::type [with T = BoostArray]’:
test.cpp:51:5:   required from here
test.cpp:37:45: error: ambiguous class template instantiation for ‘struct scalar_of<BoostArray, void>’
 using ScalarOf = typename scalar_of<T>::type;
                                             ^
test.cpp:27:8: error: candidates are: struct scalar_of<T, typename std::enable_if<has_element<T, void>::value, void>::type>
 struct scalar_of<T, EnableIf<has_element<T>>> {
        ^
test.cpp:32:8: error:                 struct scalar_of<T, typename std::enable_if<has_scalar<T, void>::value, void>::type>
 struct scalar_of<T, EnableIf<has_scalar<T>>> {
```

The clang version is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da1f3a9ac5f5f153) and works fine. The gcc version is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0525ed110caaa8bb) and fails to compile.

---

**My Question**: Is my code correct, and this an issue with GCC 4.8.1; or am I doing something wrong and Clang is being too generous when compiling? In any case, how can I change my code such that GCC 4.8.1 would compile it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like it's [yet another manifestation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833356/is-there-a-compiler-bug-exposed-by-my-implementation-of-an-is-complete-type-trai/25833474#25833474) of [CWG issue 1558](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558). The standard was unclear whether unused template arguments in alias templates can result in substitution failure. Clang treats it as substitution failure; GCC simply ignores the unused arguments.

Use

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct make_void { typedef void type;};

template<typename... Ts>
using ToVoid = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;
```

instead and [you should see it compile in both compilers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9350f4e45eaf136).